# Deleting an SRR file attachment

Tags: avi, divx, xvid

Can an attached SRR file be deleted without affecting the video file which it is attached to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes

> An SRR file is used to re-create a RAR file. If you are just downloading files, you can ignore SRR files. They are similar to SFV files and only contain "meta" information. That is, they only contain information about the other files that they come along with. SRRs do not contain any audio, video, or anything else in which the average downloader might be interested. ([more](http://www.techsono.com/faq/srr.html))